# JavaScript: 404 page, how to get the requested url?

Tags: javascript

I'm hosting few static web pages on GitHub (gh-pages). If the user tries to access a page which isn't available, he/she is moved to a custom 404.html.

What I'm wondering is if is it possible to access the original requested URL from the custom 404.html, using just JavaScript? There's no PHP nor any other server side technology available.

I've looked at the [JavaScript's Location-object](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javalocation.html) but that seems to give only the access to the current URL (in this case the 404.html) but not to the original requested URL. What I'm trying to achieve is a 404.html which gives suggestion like "Did you mean to access url ..." to the user but in order to do so, I need the access to the original URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your only hope would be `document.referrer` but of course GH would need to set it, which is highly unlikely for any page returning a HTTP 404 out of a request ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the url in `document.referrer`

Answer (score 0):

Because the user is moved by the server to a 404 page, JavaScript cannot know abot the requested url.
It may be posible if you add in .htaccess to redirect the user to a page with the url: page.php?url=requested_url , then the requested_url appears in the address bar, which can be read by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with a custom domain and `location.href` will actually give the current url, which in this case is the *faulty* one. So, while `document.referrer` will only give empty string, `location.href` will give the url you want.

I'm wondering if this has to do with what kind of GH pages you're hosting as well as if you're using a custom domain. My understand was, however, that it was only possible to serve a custom 404.html using a custom domain.