# Handle 404 with .htaccess and javascript?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have a site using static html; there aren't any PHP or CGI services available. I'd like to build a somewhat intelligent 404 error page in javascript. From [JavaScript: 404 page, how to get the requested url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852263/javascript-404-page-how-to-get-the-requested-url) I understand `document.referer` is not available to the receiving 404 page, however one of the answers there suggests it might be possible to pass the request url via htaccess. How might I do that? The following doesn't work:

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /err404.html?url=%{HTTP_REFERER}
```

and `err404.html`:

```
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var file;
    file = window.location.pathname;
    document.write('sorry, ' + file + ' not found');
</script>
<body></html>
```

The resulting url remains the same as incoming, `http://www.example.com/something-not-here`

Comment: It works for me, even without `?url=%{HTTP_REFERER}` (because I do not get redirected; the url stays the same but the 404-document is loaded). `/err404.html` is relative to your root-directory, not to the `.htaccess`-file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   # `!-d` means if directory doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   # if file doesn't  ... 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l   # if link doesn't

# L = last rule, stop processing
# QSA = Query String Append
# R = Redirect (default is 302, temporary)
RewriteRule ^ /err404.html?url=%{REQUEST_URI}&refr=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L,QSA,R]
```

Then change your err404.html like this:

```
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getQueryVariable(variable) {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split('&');
       for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split('=');
           if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
               return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
           }
       }
       console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
   }
   document.write('sorry! ' + getQueryVariable('url') + 
                  ' not found, requesting URL: ' + getQueryVariable('refr'));
</script>
<body></html>
```

This will result in following text getting displayed for a **non-existing URI** like `http://domain.com/not-here` on a page `http://domain.com/sample.html`

```
sorry! /not-here not found, requesting URL: http://domain.com/sample.html
```

Comment: thanks! that's gives me what I was looking for  -- only now that I have it I realize it may not be what I *should* do! It might be better to leave a broken link a broken link (404 instead of 302). @christopher's comment may be closer to the core.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, that's because `window.location` will always give the URL displayed by the browser. The rewritten URL is only available on the server end, so you'll need a server-side language to accomplish that.